# SQL schema design with foreign key constraint for tenants

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-schema, multi-tenant

I am designing a database for use in a multi-tenant scenario.
I have recently learnt that in order to enforce that tenant_ids are consistent among tables that reference each other, I need to have the primary key of the tables to include both the table id and also the tenant_id. The foreign keys then have to reference both the table id and also the tenant_id.

This seems to be working as intended, but what if I have tables that don't reference the tenant? In my example below I have a playlist_item that doesn't reference the tenant directly. A problem I see here is that the playlist_item potentially might reference a piece of content that does not have the same tenant as the playlist it belongs to.

A possible solution would be to also include the tenant_id into all tables that exists in the database in order to be able to reference the tenant all the time, but this seems a bit cumbersome to me because the playlist_item (in this case) already has an implied tenant_id thru its owner relationship with playlist.

I would appreciate some insight into what would be a good solution in this case, and also if there are any alternative ways of achieving the same goal without potential risks of inconsistent data.

(This is just a sample, not the actual database)

[image: Sample schema design]

Comment: Referenced columns (in a foreign key relationship) must always form a unique key (primary key or unique constraint in PostgreSQL) in the referenced table. So you actually can't create the example above, unless `id` is the primary key in both `playlist` and `content`. If it is a unique constraint then it makes no sense for it to be "just" part of the primary key (because it is unique itself). In other words: you should decide what entities could have overlapping IDs (across tenants). Your `user` table f.ex. could have.

Comment: You are correct, I need to also have a unique index on the table id. The result is: Primary Key (id, tenant_id) and Unique (id). Right?

Comment: that's technically possible, but the primary key should always be the smallest set of columns which are unique. So one possibility to create your tables with an `id` as a primary key and include the `tenant_id` to *some* of them (if they can be connected to tenants through another foreign keys then it is not required) or use an `id` + `tenant_id` primary key everywhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two basic options here.

The first is to add additional foreign keys and unique constraints which include a `tenant_id` and if you do this you can ensure that the same tenant is referenced across the board.  Do this if you want to use row-level security policies because it will solve a bunch of performance problems in checking security.

In this case playlist would have a second unique index on `(id, tenant_id)` and playlist_item would have a foreign key on `(playlist_id, tenant_id)` referencing that.

Your second option is to drop the `tenant_id` where it is transitively referenced.  In this case you can always look it up via a join, but this performs poorly when tying to use row-level security.